# How to perform Inline-navigation on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to navigate across same web page? Like i want to put the control of cursor to division which has all the data on click of some button on navigation bar on same web page.

Comment: yes. I was looking for accessibility and ChromeVox is showing different effect while using inline navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `#` to do this. So for example, your menu could have something like:

```
<a href="#sectionOne">Go to section one</a>
<a href="#sectionTwo">Go to section two</a>
```

and your page "sections" would look like this:

```
<div><a name='sectionOne' /></div>
<div><a name='sectionTwo' /></div>
```

here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/mFqCM/